# What is the reason of redis memory loss?

Tags: memory, redis

Nobody flush DB, only do `hget` after start and `hset` all the Data.
But after sometime(about 1 day) , the memory will loss and no data exists...

```
# Memory
used_memory:817064
used_memory_human:797.91K
used_memory_rss:52539392
used_memory_peak:33308069304
used_memory_peak_human:31.02G
used_memory_lua:36864
mem_fragmentation_ratio:64.30
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0
```

After I restart the server and `hset` all again , the `used_memory` recover back.

```
# Memory
used_memory:33291293520
used_memory_human:31.00G
used_memory_rss:33526530048
used_memory_peak:33291293520
used_memory_peak_human:31.00G
used_memory_lua:36864
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.01
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0
```

But it can never last longer than 1 day...The `hset` process need at least 4h, and redis takes up over half of the memory so `BGSAVE` is useless...
What is the reason of memory loss? and how 2 backup data?

Comment: How much RAM does that server have? How much free RAM does it have? What's the value of your Redis' `maxmemory` and `maxmemory-policy`? What's the server's and the Redis process uptime? Do you have data persistence enabled? What does the log say?

Comment: using top:
Mem:  65855392k total, 64129460k used,  1725932k free,     9952k buffers
Swap: 32997372k total,   603208k used, 32394164k free,  6056764k cached

Comment: using top:
Mem:  65855392k total, 64129460k used,  1725932k free,     9952k buffers
Swap: 32997372k total,   603208k used, 32394164k free,  6056764k cached
maxmemory is zero, redis-uptime at most 24h, AOF open and dmp closed, and I can not find anything useful in logs althou I have set it 2 most detail level.

Comment: Sounds like Redis is getting killed by the OS due to OOM (out of memory) - look in /var/log/syslog and you'll probably find the message there. It would be best if you limit the amount of RAM that Redis tries to use with the `maxmemory` directive. A prudent value is about 1/3 of the total RAM of the server.